# Android, UnknownHostException: www.google.com, on device,not emulator

Tags: java, android, google-api-java-client

I'm using google api java client for connecting to Google Docs in Android app.
Once in a while i get following exception:

```
UnknownHostException: www.google.com
```

Code:

```
transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
ClientLogin authenticator = new ClientLogin();
authenticator.authTokenType = "writely";
authenticator.username = username.getText().toString();
authenticator.password = password.getText().toString();
authenticator.transport = transport;
authenticator.authenticate().getAuthorizationHeaderValue();
```

Device reset clears exception but is it necessary.
I suspected for DNS caching and tried following but didnt work. Im not behind a proxy as far I know.

```
Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl","0");
System.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl","0");
System.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl","0");
System.setProperty("net.eth0.dns1","8.8.8.8");
System.setProperty("net.dns1","8.8.8.8");
```

Last time it occurred was this morning when one network connection "died", cell  auto got second one, tried to do ClientLogin but failed with exception.

Just to make it clear, Im talking about DEVICE (htc desire hd), not emulator.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your **AndroidManifest.xml** file, just after the `<manifest>` tag and before the `<application>` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score -2):

I run into this daily. I think it is a bug in the emulator. After reset of emulator it works again and it never happened on a real device.

Edit: most definitely a bug in the emulator. See this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/778f94cbe647c585?pli=1). There are also several posts on StackOverflow regarding those emulator connection issues.

Comment: He said on device not emulator.